# How to customize the figure numbering with a letter or special symbol?

Tags: numbering, captions

I want to distinguish the `figure` number by adding a letter, say "a", or a special symbol, such as `\star`, between the word "Figure" and number.

In other word, what I'd like to have is something like this

> Figure a 1 
>   or
>
> Figure *1

Thank you.

Comment: A way, I see, might be, to look up the definition of the `\caption`-command and redefine it by an indentical command excerpt for the inserted "Adition". Shall "a" be a counter too, or just a letter?

Comment: Package `caption` allows to define formats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two versions: One with `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` and the other one by redefining the figure counter, but this will also change the appearance of `figure` in `List of Figures`, as such I don't recommend this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}




\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\specialformattingstuff}{*} % or use \textasteriskcentered


\let\origthefigure\thefigure

\DeclareCaptionFormat{cancaption}{#1#2#3\par} % Normal format actually
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{cancaptionlabel}{#1 \specialformattingstuff#2}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\captionsetup[figure]{format=cancaption,labelformat=cancaptionlabel}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Foo figure}
\end{figure}

% Redefinition of counter output -- I don't recommend this
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{a \origthefigure}
% Restore to the default format 
\captionsetup[figure]{format=plain,labelformat=default}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Foo figure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer, Great!! thank you very much!

Comment: @can: You're welcome. Please use the `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` way -- it's cleaner and better!

Answer (score 6):

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
```

Comment: This is much simpler.