# How do I add a prefix to references?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm writing up solutions to a book. The book already has all its contents labeled as `Figure 1.5`, `Equation 2.13` etc. I'd like to label my own figures and equations without suffering any collisions with the main text. For example `Figure S-1.5` or `Equation S-2.13` might do. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you use plain `\ref` (so no `cleveref`, `nameref`, `autoref` etc) then you could just do `\newcommand{\myref}[1]{S-\ref{#1}}`.

Comment: But that only relabels the occurrence of `Figure 1.5` to `Figure S-1.5` in the text, doesn't it? The figure itself will still be titled `Figure 1.5`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of that - maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305302/how-to-customize-the-figure-numbering-with-a-letter-or-special-symbol can help you?

Comment: What do you mean by "my own figures and equations"?

Comment: My solutions contain figures and equations. And sometimes I want to reference an equation in the main text, sometimes I want to reference a figure in my own solutions. I don't want to use the same referencing scheme for both.

In case it wasn't clear: I'm not the author of the book.

Comment: Related: [How exactly does `\def\p@figure{Figure~}` work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5797/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number that appears in both figure captions and references is determined by the macro`\thefigure`. It is effectively defined as `\arabic{figure}` if you are using `article`, and as `\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\fi\arabic{figure}` if you are using `book` or `report`. The macro `\theequation` does the same thing for equations.

You can thus accomplish what you want by prepending `S-` to the definitions of `\thefigure` and `\theequation`, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} %% <- for \eqref, optional

\let\theequationWithoutS\theequation %% <- store old definition
\renewcommand\theequation{S-\theequationWithoutS}
\let\thefigureWithoutS\thefigure %% <- store old definition
\renewcommand\thefigure{S-\thefigureWithoutS}

%% Alternative:
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \pretocmd{\theequation}{S-}{}{}
% \pretocmd{\thefigure}{S-}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{myeq}
    \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac1{1+\cos(x)^{\sin(x)}} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac\pi2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rule{2cm}{2cm} %% black box
    \caption{\label{myfig}This is a figure.}
\end{figure}

This sentence contains references to Figure~\ref{myfig} and Equation~\eqref{myeq}.

\end{document}
```

[image]